# What kind of Barcode hash/encryption is this

Tags: barcode

I am scanning from a barcode reader but it shows every thing like this the string like this when it scans

```
L008EtZmqQ41daYYVhz000007IU7I#
L00A3RZmqRKOMmp13hy000007IU7I#
```

But when I use their software the output will be like this which is the actual value which I need it

```
07117340277500r
```

Bottom is the barcode image which I scans, Can anyone tell me what kind of the barcode type is this or any other way to decrypt the above mentioned codes into the actual value it would be great help
[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looks like its a Code 39 barcode, look if there's some library or something to decode it.

Source: https://barcode-labels.com/getting-started/barcodes/types/